# Create file and download it php

Tags: php, html, download

I'm trying to generate a .html file and download it.

My issue: First i check if file exists, if true i delete it and create a new one.

When i click to generate file, the downloaded file is always the first file created and isnt updated. I've checked the file manualy and its ok but the downloaded is the old one. If i delete the file on server i can download anyway.

check the site: bit.ly/1crrcif

```
$content =  "<html></head></head><body>All content here</body></html>";

   if( empty( $error )){ 

   echo "<h3>File generated</h3>";
   $my_file = 'change_nameto_index.html';
   if (file_exists($my_file)) {
       echo "file exists";
      unlink($my_file);
   }

   $new_file = 'change_nameto_index.html';
   $handle = fopen($new_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$new_file);
   $data = $content;
   fwrite($handle, $data);
   fclose($handle);
   echo "<a download='change_nameto_index.html' href='change_nameto_index.html'>"
      . "<b class='download'>Download</b></a>"
      ;
```

Comment: Not closed:  if( empty( $error )){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution 1:
try to add this to your download page head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Solution 2:

i think it's a 'cache problem'. try this:

```
echo "<a download='index.html?".time()."' href='index.html?".time()."'><b class='download'>Download</b></a>";
```

this isn't the best way but probably the fast (and easy) one

adding a parameter that is every time different (with '?' and time()) will make the browser thinking that the download page is also different, so it will download it's latest version

Comment: I've tryied with this solution and it works well but i'm searching for another option, could you help?

Answer (score 1):

**Faking each link to be new**

One technique to prevent downloadables to get cached is providing a time stamp to 'fake' each link to the same script as new. Instead of

```
  someScript.php
```

one uses

```
   someScript.php?notUsedParameter=342342376
```

Noe, that the parameter `notUsedParameter` isn't used by the script. It is simply used to mark the link to `someScript.php` as a new one to client browser.

This common technique is the most frequently used and **probably most stable one**.

The next technique somehow depends on the browser. E.g. **Internet Explorer is a bit picky about cache / proxy control headers.**

Before and including IE 8, certain cache / proxy control headers effectively prevent SSL based download request. Microsoft is aware of the problem and proposes registry changes.

**Forcing the browser / proxy to not save link's content**

Another option is to tell the browser / proxy to not cache the current request.

```
header('Pragma: public');   
header('Expires: 0');       
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Last-Modified: Date Wed, 19 Feb 2000 23:45:13 GMT' );
header('Cache-Control: private', false);
```